# how to disable ssl redirect in bugzilla

Tags: ssl, redirect, bugzilla

In my Bugzilla setup I made a rookie mistake of enabling SSL without any SSL mods loaded on Apache. Now i can't access Bugzilla site using either https or http (obviously :(.

Can you someone pls tell me how to disable or turn off the ssl_redirect option?

Thanks
Sri

Comment: It may help people answer to know some more about your setup. What is the host OS? What is the database backend?

Comment: Im running it on redhat and mysql

Comment: I won't stick this as an answer, because I can't test it.  Start mysql, switch to the database you're using for Bugzilla, look for a table which stores options, find the option you've set and change the value using the appropriate SQL.

Answer (score 1):

edit your `data/params` file, change `ssl_redirect` to `0`.